# The assigned value is never used

Tags: java

Hace unos días me salió un error en un ejercicio que no logro resolver.

En el siguiente código que les mostraré, en la línea `Boolean Decreciente = False;` larga un error llamado *"The assigned value is never used"*, pero el mismo es usado después en el programa y/o el boolean anterior llamado `Creciente` cumple una función similar y este no larga dicho error. Programa utilizado: Netbeans.

Código

```
int[] Número= new int[10];
boolean Creciente=false;
boolean Decreciente=false; //inicio del error
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){Número[i]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el "+(i+1)+"º número"));}
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    if(Número[i] < Número[i+1]){Creciente = true;}
    if(Número[i] > Número[i+1]){Decreciente=true;} //sigue el error
}
/*Resto el código inutilizable por el error boolean*/
if(Creciente=true && Decreciente=false){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo es Creciente");}
else if(Creciente=false && Decreciente=true){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo es Decreciente");}
else if(Creciente=true && Decreciente=true){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo esta Desordenado");}
else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo esta Igualado");}
```

Comment: Primeramente eso no es un error, es una advertencia del IDE que te está diciendo que un determinado objeto nunca es usado. De hecho no lo usas nunca porque los `if` están mal, para comparar si un valor es verdadero o falso tendrías que usar: `==` o simplemente usarlo con el `if` directamente dado que es un booleano (en cuyo caso pondrías `!` delante para preguntar si es falso). O sea, así: `if(Creciente==true && Decreciente==false)` o así: `if(Creciente && !Decreciente)`  y así con todos los `if` que tienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender un poco más este concepto, tienes que descifrar lógicamente que es aplicación, declaración, asignación y un largo etc de la oratoria usual del programador.

```
boolean Decreciente=false; //DECLARACION Y ASIGNACION
```

¿Por qué es una declaración? R: Porque le damos nombre y tipo a la variable
¿Por qué es una asignación? R: Porque le damos un valor

```
boolean Decreciente; // DECLARACION
```

Aquí aún no le hemos dado un valor...

```
if(Número[i] > Número[i+1]){Decreciente=true;} // ASIGNACION
```

Ahora el valor de *Decreciente* es *true*

---

Muy bien, ahora tenemos declaración y asignación, pero realmente no estás usando su valor, ¿Por qué? porque si eliminas esas líneas de código el programa continúa funcionando de la misma manera, no tiene una *aplicación* en su valor, el contenido de esa variable nunca es comparado/usado en el código.

```
if(Decreciente == true) // APLICACION
```

¿Por qué es una aplicación? R: Estamos usando el *VALOR* de la variable para asignar más instrucciones a nuestro código. Los IDE te ayudan a detectar cuando una variable no es utilizada, y es con ese mensaje, que en realidad es un WARNING, no es un error.

En los if los **BOOLEANOS** tienen comparaciones implicitas que no requiren colocar true == **variable** y para negar basta con usar: **"!"**

```
    if(Creciente && !Decreciente){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo es Creciente");
    }
    else if(!Creciente && Decreciente){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo es Decreciente");
    }
    else if(Creciente && Decreciente){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo esta Desordenado");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo esta Igualado");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo veo es que las siguientes condiciones no están bien establecidas. Cuando quieres evaluar el contenido de una variable dentro de un `if` se debe utilizar el doble igual `==`, ya que un igual `=` significa asignación de valor. Te dejo la parte del código con las correcciones. Y como recomendación: no utilices acentos ni caracteres especiales en los nombres de las variables.

```
 /*Resto el código inutilizable por el error boolean*/
            if (Creciente == true && Decreciente == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo es Creciente");
            } else if (Creciente == false && Decreciente == true)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo es Decreciente");
            }
            else if (Creciente == true && Decreciente == true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo esta Desordenado");
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo esta Igualado");
            }
```